# How to override Wordpress's core block save function?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

All I want to do is override a core block's save function to render the frontend with different html. When I was on Wordpress 5.3 I was able to override and make it a dynamic block (which I prefer) with php:

```
register_block_type( 'core/file', array(
'render_callback' => 'custom_core_block_render_cb',));
```

But now I've updated to Wordpress 5.6 there's a Wordpress notice saying *"WP_Block_Type_Registry::register was called incorrectly. Block type "core/file" is already registered."*

Is this notice important enough for me to not ignore it? If no, then is there a way to get around it without resorting to overriding the save() on the javascript side with `blocks.registerBlockType` since all it does it bring future problems and break the block in the future if I need to make updates (this really urks me). Also would rather not copy the entire block.

Comment: Why don't you filter the output of the block instead of trying to register it again? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: I'll post an answer since this is valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to re-register a core block. WP core blocks have a filter to change the output: `render_block`

Here's the filter:
`apply_filters( 'render_block', string $block_content, array $block )`

Here's the usage:

```
// Two arguments
add_filter( 'render_block', 'so66910341_core_file_output', 10, 2 );

function so66910341_core_file_output( string $block_content, array $block ) {
    if ( $block['blockName'] === 'core/file' ) :
         // update the $block_content here
         $updated_content_markup = '<html stuff>';
         $updated_content_markup .= $block_content;
         $updated_content_markup .= '</closing html stuff>';
         
         return $updated_content_markup; // or whatever variable you use.
    endif;

    // Return the original block content if it's not a core/file block.
    return $block_content;
}
```

Here's the documentation:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/

Answer (score 1):

Better solution for Wordpress 5.5 - change only `render_callback`

```
add_filter( 'register_block_type_args', 'custom_register_block_type_args', 10, 3 );
function custom_register_block_type_args( $args, $name ) {
    if( $name == 'core/file' ) {
        $args['render_callback'] = 'custom_core_block_render_cb';
    }
    return $args;
}
```